# url change for post and get in ngresource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 2 urls, one serving POST method and other GET method

http://1.2.3.4:1234/UASAPI/UserServices - It is with POST and requires request body and nothing in parameters.

http://1.2.3.4:1234/UASAPI/UserServices/9959116790/123456 - It is GET and input is given in parameters.

Inside services.js, I am using for post call as below

```
.factory('User', ['$resource',function($resource){
    return $resource('http://205.147.99.162:8080/UASAPI/UserServices');
}])
```

I am using it as below to make post call and its working.

```
User.save(angular.toJson(userAndAttributesValues), function(res){},function(res){});
```

Now how should I add the GET method serving url inside User factory to serve for get() & query() methods of ngresource.

How should I invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you could set up your [**`factory`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe) to return both functions:

```
.factory('User', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return {
      postData: function() {
        return $resource('http://205.147.99.162:8080/UASAPI/UserServices');
      },
      getData: function() {
        return $resource('http://1.2.3.4:1234/UASAPI/UserServices/9959116790/123456');
      }      
    }
}])
```

Then use them as needed:

```
User.postData()
User.getData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to ngResource...

Call like this

```
// get the data
$scope.posts = Post.get({param1:1, param2:2});

// save some data
Post.save()
```

Set up resource like this

```
angular.module('app',['ngResource'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Post) {

    $scope.post = new Post();
    $scope.posts = Post.get({param1:1, param2:2});
    Post.save()

  }).provider('Post', function() {
    this.$get = ['$resource', function($resource) {
      var API = $resource('http://205.147.99.162:8080/UASAPI/UserServices/:param1/:param2', {
        param1: "@param1",
        param2: "@param2"
      });

      return API;
    }];
  });
```